# How to tokenization in English with Stanza

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, tokenize, stanza

```py
text = "XXXXXX，XXXX “XX” ， XXXXX 50 XX 、 XXXXXXXXX、XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

zh_nlp = stanza.Pipeline('zh')
doc = zh_nlp(text)

for sent in doc.sentences:
  print("Tokenize:" + ' '.join(token.text for token in sent.tokens))
```

stanza is capable of separating text if it is entered in Chinese (Chinese relies heavily on Tokenization & Sentence Segmentation). It outputs the following. It's roughly divided like this.

```
Tokenize:XXX XX X ， X X XX “ XX ” ， X X X XX 50 X X 、 XXX XXXX XX 、 X X XX XX X XX XX XX X XX XX X 。
```

If the output is in English, it is separated by the English word space.

```py
text = "Hong Kong"

en_nlp = stanza.Pipeline('en')
doc = en_nlp(text)

for sent in doc.sentences:
  for Tokenize in sent.tokens:
    print(Tokenize)
```

For example, if the input program is "Hong Kong", the output will look like this.

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "text": "Hong",
    .......
  }
]
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "text": "Kong",
    .......
  }
]
```